# Как редактировать проект на Laravel?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, composer

Имеется готовый проект на Laravel. Сайт с бд MySQl имеются все исходные файлы .Как его добавить в PhpStorm(или как еще)  для редактирования?

Answer (score 0):

В PhpStorm есть несколько способов.

Самый простой: в верхнем меню нажимаете `File` и в меню выбираете `Open Directory`, дальше выбираете проект в проводнике, спрашивает открыть в текущем или в новом окне и все.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]